# $(a \star b)^k = a^k \star b^ k$ is not true for two consecutive integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have $k$ in the group $(G, \star)$ for three consecutive integers $$\forall a,b \in G \quad (a \star b)^k = a^k \star b^ k$$
The prove for showing $(G, \star)$ is commutative is as follow:

$(ab)^i=a^ib^i$.
$(ab)^{i+1}=a^{i+1}b^{i+1}$.
$(ab)^{i+2}=a^{i+2}b^{i+2}$.

$(ba)^i=a^{-1}(ab)^{i+1}b^{-1}=a^{-1}(a^{i+1}b^{i+1})b^{-1}=a^ib^i$.
So, $(ab)^i=(ba)^i$.

$(ba)^{i+1}=a^{-1}(ab)^{i+2}b^{-1}=a^{-1}(a^{i+2}b^{i+2})b^{-1}=a^{i+1}b^{i+1}$.
So, $(ab)^{i+1}=(ba)^{i+1}$.

Let $c:=(ab)^i=(ba)^i$.
$(ab)c=(ab)(ab)^i=(ab)^{i+1}=(ba)^{i+1}=(ba)(ba)^i=(ba)c$.
So, $ab=ba$ by cancellation law.

But I want to show that we can't say the same thing for two consecutive integers.

So assume that $i$ and $i+1$ are two consecutive integers. We can't say $i+2$ is too because I say maybe it's not in the domain. So for showing that we can't have the same result for only 2 consecutive integers:

$(ab)^i=a^ib^i$.
$(ab)^{i+1}=a^{i+1}b^{i+1}$.

$(ba)^i=a^{-1}(ab)^{i+1}b^{-1}=a^{-1}(a^{i+1}b^{i+1})b^{-1}=a^ib^i$.
So, $(ab)^i=(ba)^i$.

$(ba)^{i+1}=a^{-1}(ab)^{i+2}b^{-1}$

Here's the problem. Because we don't have $i+2$ as consecutive integer for $i$ and $i+1$. So we can't continue the prove and it's not true.

Do I have the true idea for it?

Comment: Again, you can compare with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387803/if-abk-ak-bk-for-two-consecutives-integers-k-is-g-abelian), how "true" the idea for only two integers $k$ is. Then $G$ need not be abelian. For three successive $k$ you have asked this already a few hours ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618108/prove-a-star-bk-ak-star-b-k).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you